# Want to convert a unsigned short hexadecimal to a array of chars containing the character versions of the digits (in C)`

Tags: c

I am writing a C program and I would like to convert an unsigned short to a array of chars.
For example:
0x1234 --> "1234"
Is this possible? And if so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: "I am writing a C program" --> Post that code.

Comment: Always post the code. it will useful for others who help you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "sprintf" function to place your variable into a character using the "%x" format.  Following is a simple snippet of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[16];
    unsigned short x = 0x1234;
    sprintf(str, "%x", x);
    printf("Characters are: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Short/bin/Release$ ./Short 
Characters are: 1234
```

Give that try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.